# Disqus comment system not show

Tags: plugins, theme-development, comments, disqus

I've installed the disqus comment system plugin. I need some help to use it, I'm not able to display the comment box inside my post or pages. I'm using a custom theme, and there is no a comment.php file. Is this a problem?
Here is my loop code

```
<div class="row feed" id="" style="padding: 2.5em 0 1em 0;">
          <?php if( $menu_feed->have_posts() ): ?>
          <?php while( $menu_feed->have_posts() ): $menu_feed->the_post(); ?>
            <section>
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-lg-7 col-xl-7 " id="pagesThumb">
                <img class="img-fluid thumb" src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" >
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-xl-5 in-menu" id="pageInMenu">
                <h4 class="page-link"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                  <?php the_content(); ?>
                <a class="btn btn-link float-right next" href="" onclick=""><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 comment-box">
                <?php comments_template(); ?>
              </div>
            </section>
          <?php endwhile; ?>
          <?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have followed the settings that have been recommended in

[WpDiscuz Comment Display Settings](https://wpdiscuz.com/docs/wpdiscuz-documentation/discussion-settings/comment-display-settings/)